# How to solve mingw32-make.exe exited with code 2 error?

Tags: c++, qt, mingw

I've installed `Qt Open source 4.8.3` library for Windows on `Windows 8 Pro x64`, `Qt Creator 2.6.0` and `MingW 4.4.0` manually. From Qt Creator I've setup kits and compilers. I opened the analog clock example comes along with Qt Creator and rebuild the project. The following error are emitted by the compiler.

```
Running steps for project analogclock...

Starting: "C:\Qt\4.8.3\bin\qmake.exe" C:\Qt\4.8.3\examples\widgets\analogclock\analogclock.pro -r -spec win32-g++

The process "C:\Qt\4.8.3\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.

Starting: "C:\MingW\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 

C:/MingW/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release

mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `C:/Qt/4.8.3/examples/widgets/analogclock-build-Desktop-Release'

g++ -c -O2 -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -DQT_NO_DYNAMIC_CAST -I"..\..\..\include\QtCore" -I"..\..\..\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\include" -I"..\..\..\include\ActiveQt" -I"release" -I"..\analogclock" -I"." -I"..\..\..\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o release\analogclock.o **..\analogclock\analogclock.cpp**

mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Qt/4.8.3/examples/widgets/analogclock-build-Desktop-Release'

mingw32-make[1]: *** [release/analogclock.o] Error 1

mingw32-make: *** [release] Error 2

The process "C:\MingW\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.

Error while building/deploying project analogclock (target: Desktop)

When executing step 'Make'
```

I've verified that **C:/Qt/4.8.3/examples/widgets/analogclock/analogclock.cpp** exists. Besides, this project comes with Qt installation and I didn't change anything.

Why is this error occurring and how can i fix it?

Comment: Have you tried running the `g++ ...` command yourself, and seeing what errors it gives you? It looks like make isn't giving you anything useful.

Comment: Does the output directory (i.e., the `release` directory) exist in the expected location?

Comment: @Xymostech: When I tried to run g++, I got system error saying "libgmp-3.dll" was not found. I searched MinwG and found libgmp-10.dll. I guess I need to install older version of libgmp?

Comment: Make sure the mingw bin directory is in your path.  This should at least take care of the "libgmp-3.dll" error.

Comment: Have you installed Release versions of Qt libs? Anyway, try to build Debug version of `analogclock`.

Comment: @mark: mingw bin is in the path.

Comment: @redmode: i've installed release version of Qt. i tried both debug and release version of my own project which didn't work. i'll try building debug build of analogclock but i don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems your installation of g++ is not clean, so the compiler cannot be launched (this is also what you've said in the comments). Try reinstall, and then you can try to build a hello world program to verify whether you can run g++. Also, please verify that your PATH variable is properly configured for mingw.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bad mingw installation. Are there any other unix-ish things in your %PATH%, i.e. cygwin, or msys, perl, ruby, ... or other versions of mingw?